# How to choose the fastest Websocket serve from ten Websocket serve

Tags: websocket

There are ten websocket serves all, my leader wants me to find the fastest one from it,but I have no idea,who can help me,thank you very much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fiR0.png)

now my question is how to get the fastest one,and how to prove that is the fastest

Comment: A bit hard to understand exactly what you mean, but you want to select a server with the lowest latency, or am I wrong?

Comment: yeah , so sorry i don't make myself clear ,you are right . i want to select a serve with the lowest latency